# Ubuntu 16.04 ~/.xsessionrc run twice on startup

Tags: 16.04, xorg, startup

i'm quite new to Ubuntu/Linux and i'm trying to start a desktop application at launch with a script located in `~/.xsessionrc`. The script works but for some reason `~/.xsessionrc` runs twice on startup which is causing launch errors for my desktop application.

I've looked at the `/etc/X11/` files and it seems that all the scripts in Xsession.d/ directory are also being executed twice. Im not really sure how X11 works, but a solution to this would be great.

Comment: There is another approach which is probably better: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html

Comment: The same thing happens, the script gets ran twice.

Comment: That's odd. (You need to remove the entry from `~/.xsessionrc` and possible other config file(s), of course.)

Comment: Both KDE and Gnome also have autostart features for applications. It usually makes sense to let the desktop manager start things after it's ready to run them. I'm sure some other DTEs have similar options.